Inconsistent results when inserting data from `s3cluster` to ClickHouse Cloud's SharingMergeTree tables
I'm trying to read data from GCS, aggregate them, and insert them into ClickHouse Cloud's SharingMergeTree tables.
I've come across this inconsistent behaviour when trying to insert data from GCS (read using the s3cluster function), into the target MergeTree table. Sometimes the results don't show up even though the INSERT command shows success. However, when debugging with the same command/data, sometimes they did show up properly. (Most of the time they don't)
I was thinking about the possibility that it might be caused by unmerged parts/ out-of-sync replicas, but after trying the commands below, the inconsistency in the result still persists.
The commands I tried:
-- Merge
OPTIMIZE TABLE test_db.test_inserts FINAL;

-- Also, checked that there was only one part after OPTIMIZE
select count() parts_count, database, table, partition from system.parts
where table like '%test_inserts%' and active group by database, table, partition
order by parts_count desc;

select * from system.virtual_parts where table = 'test_inserts';


-- Sync replicas
SYSTEM SYNC REPLICA test_db.test_inserts LIGHTWEIGHT;
SELECT * FROM test_db.test_inserts SETTINGS select_sequential_consistency = 1;

Unfortunately, they all didn't resolve the inconsistent issue I'm facing.
Below are the steps and queries I used. I'm not able to make it for everyone to run and reproduce the issue since I'm getting data from a private GCS bucket.

Read and aggregate data from GCS using s3cluster (note that I also tried switching to use s3 and gcs functions, but they also had the same problem).
Executing this would result in some aggregated rows (e.g, 5 rows)

SELECT 
    column_a
    countStateIf(column_b = 'abc') AS counts
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        column_a,
        column_b
    FROM s3Cluster(
        'default',
        'https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/PATH/TO/PARQUET/FILES/*.parquet', 
        '<Redacted HMAC Key>',
        '<Redacted HMAC Secret>', 
        'Parquet'
    )
) gcs
GROUP BY column_a


Add INSERT INTO at the top of the above command, and execute INSERT successfully.

INSERT INTO test_db.test_inserts

Below is the CREATE TABLE command for this table:
CREATE TABLE test_db.test_inserts
(
    `column_a` UInt16,
    `counts` AggregateFunction(count)
)
ENGINE = SharedAggregatingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{uuid}/{shard}', '{replica}')
ORDER BY (column_a)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192


Execute SELECT with countMerge on the target table. This is where inconsistency happens. Sometimes this shows the results (e.g., 5 aggregated rows) properly, sometimes they don't - even after waiting for a day or two and running all the merge/sync commands above.

SELECT
    column_a,
    countMerge(counts)
FROM test_db.test_inserts
GROUP BY 
    column_a
ORDER BY 
    column_a
;

This also happens when running through Python clickhouse_connect (sending the query through client.command). The log shows 5 rows inserted successfully but nothing shows up when SELECTing.

{'read_rows': '46324168', 'read_bytes': '480616778', 'written_rows': '5', 'written_bytes': '1960', 'total_rows_to_read': '0', 'result_rows': '5', 'result_bytes': '1960', 'elapsed_ns': '2157374876', 'query_id': '<QUERY_ID>'}

My very own guess and observation is that it usually happens with queries that insert a small amount of rows. It's only my pure guess with no proof, and I'm not using Async Inserts, so I'm not sure if that relates.
Could someone please give me some advice on this? or how should I investigate this further?

Do you see the rows in the aggregating table if you do a simple SELECT * FROM test_inserts?
Its possible your inserts are being deduplicated? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings#replicated-deduplication-window

No records are returned from a simple SELECT * FROM test_inserts

Regarding s3Cluster table function: Yes, deduplication of to-be-inserted blocks can happen when data is ingested in parallel by multiple nodes with s3Cluster, as it can happen when data is ingested by a single node only. Each insert thread on each node is collecting up to min_insert_block_size_rows or min_insert_block_size_bytes in memory. Then this data is sorted based on the table's sorting key, then a hash is computed from that block of sorted data and compared with the hashes already existing in Keeper. If the same hash already exists, the block is discarded, otherwise the block is written to a part on disk, and the hash added to Keeper.

maybe you're experiencing a deduplication window effect - see https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings#replicated-deduplication-window
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `column_a` UInt16,
    `counts` UInt16
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY tuple()

CREATE TABLE test_inserts
(
    `column_a` UInt16,
    `counts` AggregateFunction(count)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY column_a
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192


INSERT INTO test SELECT
    CAST(randUniform(5, 25), 'UInt16'),
    CAST(randUniform(5, 25), 'UInt16')
FROM numbers(1000)

SELECT
    column_a,
    count()
FROM test
GROUP BY column_a
ORDER BY column_a ASC

┌─column_a─┬─count()─┐
│        5 │      53 │
│        6 │      38 │
│        7 │      49 │
│        8 │      58 │
│        9 │      62 │
│       10 │      49 │
│       11 │      49 │
│       12 │      45 │
│       13 │      52 │
│       14 │      53 │
│       15 │      46 │
│       16 │      62 │
│       17 │      41 │
│       18 │      51 │
│       19 │      53 │
│       20 │      46 │
│       21 │      38 │
│       22 │      52 │
│       23 │      51 │
│       24 │      52 │
└──────────┴─────────┘
20 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec. Processed 1.00 thousand rows, 2.00 KB (157.78 thousand rows/s., 315.55 KB/s.)
Peak memory usage: 114.26 KiB.

SELECT
    column_a,
    countMerge(counts)
FROM test_inserts
GROUP BY column_a
ORDER BY column_a ASC

Query id: 40af56ad-66f7-411a-8c13-9668ae5e39cf

┌─column_a─┬─countMerge(counts)─┐
│        5 │                 53 │
│        6 │                 38 │
│        7 │                 49 │
│        8 │                 58 │
│        9 │                 62 │
│       10 │                 49 │
│       11 │                 49 │
│       12 │                 45 │
│       13 │                 52 │
│       14 │                 53 │
│       15 │                 46 │
│       16 │                 62 │
│       17 │                 41 │
│       18 │                 51 │
│       19 │                 53 │
│       20 │                 46 │
│       21 │                 38 │
│       22 │                 52 │
│       23 │                 51 │
│       24 │                 52 │
└──────────┴────────────────────┘

20 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.043 sec.

--repeat insert

INSERT INTO test_inserts SELECT
    column_a,
    countState() AS counts
FROM test
GROUP BY column_a

Query id: ddd73c02-fc90-4d2b-90f6-a2802abe7b53

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.152 sec. Processed 1.00 thousand rows, 2.00 KB (6.58 thousand rows/s., 13.16 KB/s.)
Peak memory usage: 1.12 MiB.

clickhouse-cloud :) SELECT
    column_a,
    countMerge(counts) FROM test_inserts GROUP BY
    column_a
ORDER BY
    column_a

SELECT
    column_a,
    countMerge(counts)
FROM test_inserts
GROUP BY column_a
ORDER BY column_a ASC

Query id: c355c15c-a289-4811-9d94-c69d96d7ffd1

┌─column_a─┬─countMerge(counts)─┐
│        5 │                 53 │
│        6 │                 38 │
│        7 │                 49 │
│        8 │                 58 │
│        9 │                 62 │
│       10 │                 49 │
│       11 │                 49 │
│       12 │                 45 │
│       13 │                 52 │
│       14 │                 53 │
│       15 │                 46 │
│       16 │                 62 │
│       17 │                 41 │
│       18 │                 51 │
│       19 │                 53 │
│       20 │                 46 │
│       21 │                 38 │
│       22 │                 52 │
│       23 │                 51 │
│       24 │                 52 │
└──────────┴────────────────────┘

20 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.008 sec.


If I understand the deduplication window effect correctly, there should be some records returned when I select. However, in my case, the test_inserts table is empty. That is, before and after executing the INSERT the result would only show as No records found.

It seems to really cause by deduplication window effect as you suggested. I added replicated_deduplication_window = 0 to disable the process and it works as expected. Thanks!
One more follow-up question. As I'm using s3cluster to insert data from GCS (with 3 nodes on ClickHouse cluster), I'm wondering if this effect would happen occasionally as the first insert pushes through while the other two got detected as duplicates?

Regarding insert deduplication, you can double-check if your inserts got ignored (because the same inserts occured in the past) by running this query against your ClickHouse Cloud instance:
select message, event_time from clusterAllReplicas('default', system.text_log) where startsWith(message, 'Deduplication') order by event_time desc;
Does that query return something for you?

Yes, it does return 45 rows, with messages like Deduplication path already exists: deduplication_path=/clickhouse/tables/ef0bbf45-60a5-4bfc-845e-f10d4e07d57e/default/blocks/all_597095351001016783_11772736627350959770

From what I understand now, it looks like I have three options:

Disable replicated_deduplication_window when creating the table - this means I'll have to accept my own risk not to let ClickHouse check for duplicated inserts.
Create a brand new table. Do not experiment on it (only insert the rows once and for all - don't delete/test/re-insert).
Add another column to make each insert non-idempotent, e.g., createdAt DateTime64(3) DEFAULT now().

Am I correct?
Also, I'm wondering do we have a way to manually clear the hash sums that are stored in ClickHouse Keeper?

You can work/experiment with just one table without deactivating automatic insert deduplication. Based on how you clear the table:
DROP table T; -- clears deduplication log
TRUNCATE table T; -- clears deduplication log
DELETE FROM T WHERE ...; -- DOES NOT clear deduplication log
